# Set default value and type for parameter

Tags: python, function, int, default

How can I do something like this:

```
def profile(request, pk=0 : int):
    #to do
```

I need `pk` to be int (without converting in function).

Like this:

```
def profile(request, pk: int):
```

If `pk` empty - set value to 0 and type to int.

Comment: If you pass `int` as argument, it will be `int` and you don't need to convert it.

Comment: You can use
def profile(request, pk: int=0 ):
but just a type hint. means it doesn't convert automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code works for any input type of pk: `integer`, `string with integer`, `string without integer`

```
import re
    def intCheck(pk):
      contains_number = bool(re.search(r'\d', pk))
      if contains_number:
        return int(re.search(r'\d+', pk).group())
      else:
        return 0

def profile(request, pk=0):
    pk = intCheck(pk)
    print(request + " " + str(pk))

profile('request', "232")
profile('request', 123)
profile('request', "no number")
```

Output:

```
request 232
request 123
request 0
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't really specify it directly in the argument field, but you can convert it right after the function declaration:

```
def profile(request, pk=0):
    pk = int(pk)
    #to do
```

It will throw an error if the passed value for `pk` cannot be converted to an int

EDIT:
I spoke too soon, apparently you can do exactly as you did, just change things around:

```
def profile(request, pk: int = 0):
    #to do
```

BTW: I just did a quick research for "specify type of argument python". Please try to research easy things like so first before asking a question, you'll get an answer quicker :)

Comment: The type annotation will **not** convert any non-integer value passed at runtime.

Comment: def profile(request, pk: int = 0):
    print(type(pk)) 
-> <class 'str'>

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't guarantee types in python. When you set the default value of pk=0, you make its default value an `int`, but someone using your function could easily call

```
profile("Hello", pk="there")
```

which would make pk of type `str`. If you absolutely need to tell the user that pk must be of type `int` then you could do something like this:

```
if type(pk) != int:
    raise ValueError('pk must be of type int, got %s instead' % type(pk) )
```